# Issues with running a compiled java program

Tags: java, ubuntu, compiler-construction

I am a Java beginner. I wrote a quintessential "Hello, World!" program. It compiles, but won't run. The terminal says there is an exception in the thread `main`, and that the class `hello` is not found. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. What could be wrong here?

The file is called hello.java.

The commands I used:

$javac hello.java
$java hello

My code is below:

```
class hello{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    system.out.print("Hello");  
}
}
```

EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I just realized that I am using openjdk7. Does that pose a problem?

Comment: Show us what command you ran to run this program.

Comment: What package is the class in, and how are you trying to run it? *edit* Beaten to it...

Comment: show ur your complete error log

Comment: Tell us whether you can see a file called hello.class anywhere.  Try running the program from the same directory that this file is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that all your code? Since you use a terminal, can you add the results of the command `ls -lR` to your question? (run it in the same directory as your original command executing the application).

Comment: I can't add it. The result is probably 1000 lines

Comment: Ah, ok - try `java -cp . hello`

Answer (score 1):

class must be: `public class hello`
system.out.print is wrong, must be: `System.out.println("Hello World");`

Comment: If syntax is wrong compilation fails. In the question @tys says the program is compiling.

Comment: @pieter, Thank you. I just tried this; however, it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: It is compiling fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is the filename hello or Hello? The only way I duplicated your problem was by having the class name wrong, and in java the class name an filename must exactly match (meaning the case too). So if your filename is Hello.java and the class name is `hello` the program will compile fine but throw the same error you mentioned. This is just a guess though.